# How to retrieve coordinates with redis on NodeJS

Tags: node.js, redis

I make a real time location server with nodejs and redis. I would like to retrieve longitude and lattitude with the **geoSearch** command.

`const drivers = await server.redis.geoSearch('drivers', {latitude, longitude}, {radius: 5, unit: 'km'})`

With these parameters I can only the members of key drivers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a nice pretty way to do that with Node Redis that doesn't work right now. I'm submitting a PR to get it fixed right after this message. It looks like this:

```js
const drivers = await redis.geoSearchWith(
  'drivers',
  { latitude, longitude },
  { radius: 5, unit: 'km' },
  [GeoReplyWith.COORDINATES])
```

The problem is that Node Redis doesn't expose the `GeoReplyWith` type. This is easily remedied by just passing in a string:

```js
const drivers = await server.redis.geoSearchWith(
  'drivers',
  { latitude, longitude },
  { radius: 50, unit: 'km' },
  ['COORDINATES'])
```